# Is there a better way to do a PopToRoot async without leaking GRefs?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

According to this bug: [bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52597](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52597) the `PopToRoot` of the `Navigation` object still leak GRefs (in fact JNI Global References)

In one application we use `Listview` really intensively and to avoid crash I had to implement a workaround using two methods :

```
/// <summary>
/// Workaround to minimize the quantity of GREFs leaked by Xamarin.Forms JMA 17.02.2017        
/// </summary>
/// <param name="animate">if set to <c>true</c> [animate].</param>
public async Task PopToRoot(bool animate)
{
    var nav = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation;

    if(animate == false) //simulate animate = false 
        for (int i = 1; i < nav.NavigationStack.Count; i++)
            if(nav.NavigationStack[i] is BaseView)
            {
                //hide the animation
                (nav.NavigationStack[i] as BaseView).IsVisible = false;
                //hide the toolbar title change
                (nav.NavigationStack[i] as BaseView).Title = (nav.NavigationStack[nav.NavigationStack.Count - 1] as BaseView).Title;
            }

    await _PopToRootInner(true);
}

/// <summary>
/// Workaround to minimize the quantity of GREFs leaked by Xamarin.Forms JMA 17.02.2017        
/// </summary>
/// <param name="animate">if set to <c>true</c> [animate].</param>
private async Task _PopToRootInner(bool animate)
{
    var nav = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation;

    await PopAsync(animate);

    if (nav.NavigationStack.Count > 1 && nav.NavigationStack[nav.NavigationStack.Count - 1] is BaseView)
        await (nav.NavigationStack[nav.NavigationStack.Count - 1] as BaseView)._PopToRootInner(animate);

}
```

My question is : Do you know any better method to do a `PopToRoot` without animation and without leaking GRefs ?

And Also, if you know how to correct the bug, I am of course interested !

Comment: Why don't you use PopAsync in loop till you get to the root?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but it could lead to `null reference exception`. To avoid it, each stacked BaseView have to pop itself.

Comment: It doesn't have to. You just need to check that you have at least one page in navigation stack